# AngularJS Template Url not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, openshift, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I am trying to set a templateUrl on a route in AngularJS using an html file in a child directory of assets.  It works fine locally.

The templates are stored at: #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/assets/templates

```
# Sets up routing
Blog.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
# Route for '/post'
$routeProvider.when('/post', { templateUrl: './assets/mainIndex.html', controller: 'PostCtrl' } )

# Default
$routeProvider.otherwise({ templateUrl: './assets/mainIndex.html', controller: 'IndexCtrl' } )])
```

I've tried leveraging asset_path, but that doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Make sure you javascript file ends in erb. (i.e. main.js.coffee.erb). asset_path should work..

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the ./ before the assets

```
$routeProvider.when('/post', { templateUrl: 'assets/mainIndex.html', controller: 'PostCtrl' } )
```

Answer (score 0):

We must both be working on the same AngularJS/Rails tutorial. I am stuck on the same part.

asset_path does work. Make sure your javascript.coffee file ends in .erb

My templates are at:

```
app/assets/templates
```

In my main.js.coffee.erb (DONT FORGET the .erb), I have the templateUrl defined as:

```
 templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('mainIndex.html')%>'
```

This works locally. Unfortunately, it still isn't working in production (I'm using OpenShift.) The precompiled files are being generated at (public/assets.) However, the asset_path always resolves to

```
GET /assets/mainIndex.html
```

rather than something like:

```
GET assets/mainIndex-435fd76973a72d658af47da0fb824bcd.html
```

In the logs, I see all of the assets GETs referencing the precompiled files, but for some reason, this templateUrl isnt. That's my next problem to solve.